# How to create AutoCad object from this handle using ObjectARX

Tags: objectarx

I have object handle and I wish create object, using ARX
Now I try
**CPtr pEnt(handle_Obj);**

But is does not result (return null ptr)
Please, tell me, how links handles, id-s, and object pointers
**Autodesk help** is to confused fo me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get objectId like this:

```
CString handle = L"ABCD";
AcDbObjectId id;
ads_name en;
ads_handent ( handle, en ) ;
acdbGetObjectId ( id , en ) ;
```

Now You can open object based on `AcDbObjectId` like this

```
AcDbEntity* ent = NULL;
Acad::ErrorStatus es;
es = acdbOpenAcDbEntity(ent, id, AcDb::OpenMode::kForRead);
```

Then You need to cast entity to object You need like this:

```
AcDbLine* line = AcDbLine::cast( ent ) ;
```